# Make return type of a function any enum in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an interface, I need to add a call signature like `[name: string]: Enum` because I want a property that can be of any type, as long as it is an enum.

How could I do this? thank you
`

Comment: we need your code, otherwise your question is off topic on SO, I am sorry

Answer (score 2):

`Enum` in TypeScript are by default compatible with `number` so the following will work:

```
{[name: string]: number}
```